# Saving space for multiple copies of same git repository with different configs

Tags: git

I have git repository with size >2GB. Our company release one version per year and supports every one of them for 5 years, so I need 5 repositories with different branches and different config.

I need almost 13GB just for .git directory (without source files and additional libraries.

Is there a way to share the .git repository information to save space? Like having central folder with most commits and small changesets unique for every project?

Comment: Are you really needing 5 repositories, or 5 working directories?
Are those 5 distinct repositories or only tags in the same repository?

Comment: it's the same repository, just different branches. I need to keep them separate because of libraries and scripts that are unique and kept outside of git for various reasons and also IDEs configured specifically for every release.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should take a look at the `git worktree` command *(git  Version 2.5.1 or greater)*.

For example:

```
# git worktree add <path> [<branch>]

$ git worktree add ../version-42/ origin/tag-v42
```

This will create a new folder containing a new working directory

From the [git-worktree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) documentation

> The new working directory is linked to the current repository, sharing everything except working directory specific files such as HEAD, index, etc.

This should save you a lot of space. **Only one thing** to remember: You can not have two working directories (worktrees) with the same branch at the same time.

---

*Additional Info*

Use `git worktree list` to get a list of registered worktrees and their respective branches

Use `git worktree prune` to update the list of worktrees (in case you deleted one or more)